# Using Money with Ecto in an embedded schema?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm getting this error when trying to use Money.Ecto.Type with an embedded schema:

```
cannot load `%{"amount" => 69999, "currency" => "USD"}` as type Money.Ecto.Type for field `amount`
```

In the docs it says the underlying field should be an integer, but I'm storing it in a map.

```
embeds_many :price, Price do
  field :amount, Money.Ecto.Type
  field :date, Timex.Ecto.DateTime
end
```

I'm a bit confused as to why this isn't working. Am I missing an import somewhere for the loader to work or is it just because I'm using the embedded schema?

Answer (score 0):

`Money.Ecto.Type` expects an integer, as specified in the documentation.

If you are positive you need to use a custom type for the underlying database field, you are either to use **`Money.Ecto.Map.Type`** type or to implement the `Ecto`’s composite type yourself.

[More info](https://github.com/kipcole9/money#serializing-to-a-postgres-database-with-ecto) on using custom types for different databases.